# Issue a html.tpl.php override from a module?

Tags: 7, theming

Is there a way to override the output of a page from a contributed module and issue your own html.tpl.php, effectively taking control of the output from the theme?

I want to do this in effort to create a unique login/registration experience, but can only seem to override the page level template, not the html level template. I see that the print module kind of does this, but is that the way to approach it?

Comment: I don't have time to flesh it out right now, but I think you could use `hook_menu_alter()` to change the `delivery callback` for the user/login path to your own version of [`drupal_deliver_html_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7). That should give you absolute control over what is rendered to the screen, although it will mean setting appropriate headers yourself

Comment: Yeah, thats where I started heading, but wasn't sure if you would need to do all that legwork.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way round it to be honest, a good example from core is the [`ajax_deliver()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_deliver/7) function, which gets the same `$page_callback_result` as `drupal_html_deliver_page()` but processes it differently. I'm not sure if you can interrupt the process any further down in a meaningful way before the theme engine gets involved

Comment: Is there any specific reason to alter the output of html.tpl.php? There are many functions that alter what that template file outputs.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, This is an interesting question. I'm also finding a way to cease the Drupal page rendering before the theme engine gets involved. The purpose is to render a page (some kind of web service) just like JSON output or whatever provided by [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) when `using_views_api_mode` is OFF.

Comment: To overtake and override the HTML of the user login page (without a new theme) specifically to control the experience of logging in / registering, the best example being FreshBooks: http://thedomainfo.com/thumbs/voicethread.freshbooks.com_small.jpg - Overtaking the HTML process here would help from removing a ton of stuff in hooks, tpl and CSS.. Just an experiment I want to do.

Comment: @Kevin, please check [my answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/55056/2792).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/24117/2792), you could simply print the page content in the menu page callback rather than returning it.

> To get data from Drupal's database and/or produced in PHP, you need a
>   page callback (in a custom module) that output the data without the
>   full layout rendering. This is easily doable by printing the content
>   of the page directly in your page callback instead of returning it.

I guess the [Print](http://drupal.org/project/print) module implemented the printer-friendly page in this way. The following is the code snippet from the module.

```
function print_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items[PRINT_PATH] = array(
    'title' => 'Printer-friendly',
    'page callback' => 'print_controller_html',
    'access arguments' => array('access print'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'print.pages.inc',
  );
  ........   
}   

/**
 * Generate an HTML version of the printer-friendly page
 *
 * @see print_controller()
 */
function print_controller_html() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  $path = filter_xss(implode('/', $args));
  $cid = isset($_GET['comment']) ? (int)$_GET['comment'] : NULL;

  // Handle the query
  $query = $_GET;
  unset($query['q']);

  $print = print_controller($path, $query, $cid, PRINT_HTML_FORMAT);
  if ($print !== FALSE) {
    $node = $print['node'];
    $html = theme('print', array('print' => $print, 'type' => PRINT_HTML_FORMAT, 'node' => $node));
    drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    drupal_send_headers();
    print $html;
    ......
}
```

According to this, the module uses the custom HTML template `print.tpl.php`. It is a HTML-level template. The module then gets the HTML by calling `theme('print',...)` and render it directly to the browser using `print $html;`.

Here is a general idea for your purpose: **mymodule.module**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['mylogin'] = array(
    'title' => 'Custom Login Page',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_custom_login_page',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
} 
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function mymodule_theme() {
  return array(
    'mylogin' => array(
      'variables' => array('page' => array()),
      'template' => 'mylogin', // mylogin.tpl.php in your module folder
    ),
  );
}
/**
 * Generate a custom login page
 * @see more in print_controller_html() in print.pages.inc of the Print module 
 */
function mymodule_custom_login_page(){
    $page = _mymodule_login_page_prerequisite(); // get/prepare necessary variables, js, css for the page
    $page['form'] = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login')); // get login form
    // prepare html in mylogin.tpl.php
    // See more in print.tpl.php() in the Print module  
    $html = theme('mylogin', array('page' => $page)); 

    drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    drupal_send_headers();
    print $html; // cease Drupal page rendering and render directly to the browser
} 
/**
 * Prepare the array for the template with common details
 * @see more _print_var_generator() in print.pages.inc of the Print module
 */
function _mymodule_login_page_prerequisite(){
    global $base_url, $language; 
    $page = array();
    $page['language']   = $language->language;
    $page['head']       = drupal_get_html_head();
    $page['title']      = '';
    $page['scripts']    = drupal_get_js();
    $page['favicon']    = '';
    // if there is a custom css file for this page
    // drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/mylogin.css');
    $page['css'] = drupal_get_css();
    $page['message'] = drupal_get_messages();
    $page['footer_scripts'] = drupal_get_js('footer');

    return $page;
}
```

Template: **mylogin.tpl.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Custom login page template
 *
 * @ingroup page
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="<?php print $page['language']; ?>" xml:lang="<?php print $page['language']; ?>">
  <head>
    <?php print $page['head']; ?>
    <title><?php print $page['title']; ?></title>
    <?php print $page['scripts']; ?>
    <?php print $page['favicon']; ?>
    <?php print $page['css']; ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>This is custom login page.</h3>
    <?php 
    if (!empty($page['message'])):
        foreach($page['message'] as $type => $message):
        ?>
            <div class="messages <?php print $type; ?>">
                <ul>
                <?php foreach($message as $msg): ?>
                    <li><?php print $msg; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <?php
        endforeach;
    endif; ?>
    <div><?php print $page['form']; ?></div>
    <?php print $page['footer_scripts']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this will customize your login page as you need.

Answer (score 2):

Both [@Sithu](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/2792/sithu) and [@Ayesh K](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1899/ayesh-k) have provided great answers. In this example, I will combine @Ayesh's method and parts of @Sithu's code for a complete solution.

[hooks_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) or [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) functions both provide a `delivery callback`, which instruct Drupal on how  you want your code wrapped. By default, Drupal sets `delivery callback` to [drupal_deliver_html_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7), which roughly tells Drupal to wrap your page in `html.tpl.php` and `page.tpl.php`.

To modify the way Drupal wraps your page, copy the function `drupal_deliver_html_page()` into your module, and modify it. Then call your new function in `delivery callback`. Drupal will then use that function to wrap your page.

## Example

Here's a working module. Place the following code into your `/sites/all/modules/MYMODULE` directory and enable the module.

Optionally, to override an existing path, substitute `hook_menu` with `hook_menu_alter`.

**MYMODULE.module**

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['login'] = array(
    'title' => 'Login',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_page',
    'delivery callback' => 'MYMODULE_deliver',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_page() {
  global $user;
  if (!$user->uid) return drupal_get_form('user_login'); // Show login for guests.
  else drupal_goto('user/' . $user->uid); // Redirect members to own profile.
}

// Code taken from drupal_deliver_html_page().
function MYMODULE_deliver($page_callback_result) {
  global $language, $base_path;
  // Pass variables to the template.
  $vars = array(
    'language' => $language->language,
    'title' => 'My Custom Login',
    'favicon' => '',
    'css' => $base_path . drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/MYMODULE.css',
    'messages' => theme_status_messages(array('display' => NULL)),
    'content' => drupal_render($page_callback_result),
  );
  echo theme('MYMODULE_login', array('vars' => $vars)); // Uses template defined in hook_theme().
  drupal_page_footer();
}

function MYMODULE_theme() {
  $items['MYMODULE_login'] = array(
    'template' => 'MYMODULE',
    'render element' => 'page',
  );
  return $items;
}
```

**MYMODULE.info**

```
name = MYMODULE
description = "Module description."
package = Custom
core = 7.x
```

**MYMODULE.tpl.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $vars['language']; ?>" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title><?php print $vars['title']; ?></title>
  <?php print $vars['favicon']; ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php print $vars['css']; ?>">
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo $vars['messages']; ?>
  <div class="content">
    <?php print $vars['content']; ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**MYMODULE.css**

```
.content { color: pink; }
```

Comment: Question: does this example work with Drupal's caching system, and would it have separate caches for different query strings?

Comment: I believe, by default Drupal caches the form and page, respectively. I am not sure of any other caching processes.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up making a custom cache for my page responses using the API.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to invest some time finding the most appropriate hook for this. 
You can try

- [hook_page_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) to change "what is going to be rendered",
- use [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to change the delivery callback for login and register menu routers,
- [use a page--user-login.tpl.php file](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) to take over the page template of the login page,
- add some template suggestions in template.php to use a different html.tpl.php file just for the login paths,
- or finally, [hook_theme_regitry_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7), to alter the theme registry and do what you wanted to do (the html.tpl.php change)

Comment: +1 Spot on! `hook_theme_registry_alter()` might not work as it will most likely change the template for all pages, but `delivery callback` will definitely work. I've additionally explored this method in my answer, here.