# Bypass drupal theme with hook_menu() function?

Tags: 7, routes

I have a page within Drupal administration where I want to bypass all of the normal Drupal theming and calculations to only show the HTML that's returned by the function. Is this possible?

```
 $items['admin/special_blank_page'] = array(
    'title' => 'PDF',
    'page callback' => 'special_blank_page',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

//...

  function special_blank_page(){
      $html ='<html><head></head><body>Only show this HTML</body></html>';
      return $html;     
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to offer an alternative to Ayesh K's solution, you can set the `delivery callback` of your menu item

> The function to call to package the result of the page callback function and send it to the browser. Defaults to drupal_deliver_html_page() unless a value is inherited from a parent menu item. Note that this function is called even if the access checks fail, so any custom delivery callback function should take that into account. See drupal_deliver_html_page() for an example.

Comment: +1. I think this is the better approach and this might work with existing menu router items as well (I haven't tried it yet though).

Comment: See also [ajax_deliver](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/function/ajax_deliver/7) for another `delivery callback` example

Comment: I've just written an example of a custom `delivery callback`, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54733#answer-138566

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you `print` the output instead of `return`ing it.

```
function special_blank_page(){
      $html ='<html><head></head><body>Only show this HTML</body></html>';
      print $html;     
  }
```