# Populate dropdown with data from database in Drupal7 using jQuery

Tags: database, javascript

Error is seen when i made a drop down list to populate data from Database.
Database : dtable
File in the template of hook_theme named : **myModueForm_theme.tpl.php**

```
<?php
$sel = "<select  name=\"select1\" id=\"select1\">
        <option value=\"\">Select...</option>
        <option value=\"data1\">data1</option>
        <option value=\"data2\">data2</option>
        <option value=\"data3\">data3</option>
        <option value=\"data4\">data4</option>
    </select>";
echo "$sel";
```

?>

**Script :**

```
jQuery("#select1").change( function(){
if( jQuery(this).val() == "data1" ) {
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo $base_url;?>?q=search/data1",
    error: function(returnval) {
        alert("Failure");
    },
    success: function (returnval) {
        alert(returnval);
        alert("Sucess"); 
    }
})
}  
});
```

The Module file which handles the database connection named: **myModule.module**

```
$items['search/data1'] = array() 
'title' => 'Add data', //page title
'description' => 'form',
'page callback' => 'search_data1',
'page arguments' => array('access content'),
'access callback' => TRUE
```

);

// In the search_data function

```
function search_data1(){  

$options="<select  name=\"select2\" id=\"select2\">"; 
$result = db_select('dtable', 'c')
    ->fields('c')
    ->execute() 
    ->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $record) {
$name = ($record->dt1);
    $options.="<option value=\"$name\">".$name."</option>"; 
    //alert(node);
    
} 
$options.= "</SELECT>";
return $options;
```

}

What I want is

- please tell me where is the error & how to solve
- I want to return the page back to the theme PHP page with the query result, but when I display back the return value from the module file, I get the whole HTML.

  Please help & treat me as a beginner.Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you post the Javascript error? Also what is it you're trying to do? Are you sure you need to do this through Javascript?

Comment: @Richard I want to load the dropdown box with the database contents. b ut when i returm the value from the "module" , iam getting full HTML content & not the required database output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)'s `delivery callback` is set to [drupal_deliver_html_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7), therefore it delivers content wrapped in a page template. You will need to modify the `delivery callback`.

## To output page content in ajax

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['search/data1'] = array() 
  'title' => 'Add data', //page title
  'description' => 'form',
  'page callback' => 'search_data1',
  'page arguments' => array('access content'),
  'delivery callback' => 'MYMODULE_ajax_deliver',
  'access callback' => TRUE
}

function MYMODULE_ajax_deliver() {
  if ($page_callback_result) echo drupal_json_output($page_callback_result);
}
```

## To output naked page content

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['search/data1'] = array() 
  'title' => 'Add data', //page title
  'description' => 'form',
  'page callback' => 'search_data1',
  'page arguments' => array('access content'),
  'delivery callback' => 'MYMODULE_custom_deliver',
  'access callback' => TRUE
}

function MYMODULE_custom_deliver($page_callback_result) {
  if ($page_callback_result) echo $page_callback_result;
}
```

To learn more about a custom `delivery callback` function, [see my other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54733#answer-138566).

Comment: but the link you provided , the answer is not dealing with ajax_deliver. Please reply

Comment: I've updated the answer. In your case it's probably better that you don't use `ajax_deliver`.

Comment: If you'd like to convert the page into ajax, follow my first example (it's updated). Just add `'delivery callback' => 'MYMODULE_ajax_deliver'` to your `hook_menu` and add a function `MYMODULE_ajax_deliver()` to convert the page into JSON.