# Override html.twig.html within custom module

Tags: 8, page-controller

According to this Drupal 7 [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54733/issue-a-html-tpl-php-override-from-a-module), I'm looking for a Drupal 8 solution to simply print the page content within a custom html.twig.html.

```
namespace Drupal\custom_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class CustomModuleController extends ControllerBase {

  public function content() {

    return [
        '#theme' => 'custommodule_page',
        '#type' => 'page',
    ];
  }
}
```

This approach seems to be working, but I am not sure how I can remove the core and theme CSS components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can completely take over the printed page if your return value is an extension of Symfony's Response class.

Here your return value is a render array so Drupal assumes it is to be rendered in a normal HTML page.

This complex looking diagram shows the flow of request to response: [image: D8 Render Pipeline] You can read more about the diagram here: https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/render/pipeline

The first takeaway on that docs page is

> Routes whose controllers return a [Response](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Response.php/class/Response/8) object bypass the pipeline below. They rely directly on the [Symfony render pipeline](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/http_kernel/introduction.html).

In other words, most of the complexity of that diagram covers the case where the return value of a controller is NOT a Response object. Returning a Response object cuts out what Drupal normally does to wrap the render array in the `html.html.twig file`.

There are a lot of examples in core of direct returning of a response object. [Here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21aggregator%21tests%21modules%21aggregator_test%21src%21Controller%21AggregatorTestRssController.php/function/AggregatorTestRssController%3A%3AtestFeed/8) is one:

```
public function testFeed($use_last_modified, $use_etag, Request $request) {
  $response = new Response();

  $last_modified = strtotime('Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT');
  $etag = Crypt::hashBase64($last_modified);

  $if_modified_since = strtotime($request->server->get('HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'));
  $if_none_match = stripslashes($request->server->get('HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'));

  // Send appropriate response. We respond with a 304 not modified on either
  // etag or on last modified.
  if ($use_last_modified) {
    $response->headers->set('Last-Modified', gmdate(DateTimePlus::RFC7231, $last_modified));
  }
  if ($use_etag) {
    $response->headers->set('ETag', $etag);
  }
  // Return 304 not modified if either last modified or etag match.
  if ($last_modified == $if_modified_since || $etag == $if_none_match) {
    $response->setStatusCode(304);
    return $response;
  }

  // The following headers force validation of cache.
  $response->headers->set('Expires', 'Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT');
  $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate');
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8');

  // Read actual feed from file.
  $file_name = drupal_get_path('module', 'aggregator_test') . '/aggregator_test_rss091.xml';
  $handle = fopen($file_name, 'r');
  $feed = fread($handle, filesize($file_name));
  fclose($handle);

  $response->setContent($feed);
  return $response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The "AggregatorTestRssController.php" helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my simple controller for a custom page response:

```
  namespace Drupal\custom_module\Controller;

  use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
  use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface;
  use Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
  use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

  class CustomModuleController extends ControllerBase implements ContainerInjectionInterface {

  protected $twig;

  public function __construct(TwigEnvironment $twig) {
    $this->twig = $twig;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static($container->get('twig'));
  }

  public function content(Request $request) {

    $response = new Response();

    $twigFilePath = drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_module') . '/templates/custom_module_page.html.twig';
    $template = $this->twig->loadTemplate($twigFilePath);

    $markup = $this->twig->loadTemplate($twigFilePath)->render();
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $response->setContent($markup);

    return $response;
  }
}
```