# Override Default Theme's 'page' TWIG template, but not the original page template pre-process hook

Tags: theming, bootstrap-theme

I'm using the default theme, Bootstrap Barrio, but for certain pages I'm overriding the `page.html.twig` template to re-arrange the layout, however I still want the pre-processing done by my theme in `bootstrap_barrio_preprocess_page` to execute so that I don't have to maintain a copy of that code inside my custom template's pre-process function, `custom_module_preprocess_page__landing`.

Is there a way to override the template, but still have the original theme's pre-process run so it can setup the default variables?
[I found this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233935/override-page-template-and-preserve-administration-navigation-bar) that seemed to imply that adding this page suggestion hook that would then reference my `page--landing` in the module that is setting things up, would achieve this, but it's not working for me.

(my template is called `page--landing`, but the theme is registered as `page__landing` and i've tried both syntax)

```php
function my_module_theme_suggestions_page(array $variables) {
  $path = explode('/', trim(\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath(), '/'));
  if (isset($path[0]) && $path[0] == 'landing') {
    return 'page--landing';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to override the `page.html.twig` template for specific pages while still benefiting from the preprocessing logic provided by your theme's `bootstrap_barrio_preprocess_page` function. To achieve this, you can follow these steps:

1. **Create a Sub-theme:**
   If you're customizing the template in your default theme (`Bootstrap Barrio`), you might consider creating a sub-theme. This will allow you to make modifications without altering the core theme's files and maintain the preprocessing logic. Refer to the theme's documentation on creating a sub-theme.
2. **Override `page.html.twig` in Sub-theme:**
   In your sub-theme, create a file named `page--landing.html.twig`. This is where you'll customize the layout for the specific landing page. You're doing this to ensure the correct template is used for your specific landing page.
3. **Add Template Suggestions:**
   You've already attempted this, but make sure you're implementing the theme suggestion correctly in your sub-theme's `my_subtheme.theme` file. In this file, use the correct function name (`my_subtheme_theme_suggestions_page`), and return an array of suggestions. It's important to ensure that the suggestion corresponds to the template file you've created (`page--landing.html.twig`).

   ```php
   function my_subtheme_theme_suggestions_page(array $variables) {
     $suggestions = [];

     // Get the current path.
     $path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
     $args = explode('/', $path);

     // Check if the first path component is 'landing'.
     if (!empty($args[0]) && $args[0] == 'landing') {
       $suggestions[] = 'page__landing';
     }

     return $suggestions;
   }
   ```
4. **Ensure Preprocessing Logic is Executed:**
   Ensure that your sub-theme's preprocessing function is named correctly and is placed in the `my_subtheme.theme` file:

   ```php
   function my_subtheme_preprocess_page__landing(array &$variables) {
     // Your preprocessing logic here.
   }
   ```

   The above function should be placed in the `my_subtheme.theme` file of your sub-theme. Replace `my_subtheme` with the actual machine name of your sub-theme.
5. **Clear Cache:**
   After adding the theme suggestion function and the template, clear Drupal's cache to ensure the changes are recognized.

By following these steps, you should be able to create a custom template for your landing page while retaining the preprocessing logic from your sub-theme. Make sure that your sub-theme's preprocessing function is properly named and placed in the `my_subtheme.theme` file.

Comment: Thanks @Z CHAMP, I'm doing this in a custom module instead of the sub-theme, but it uses the same approach. I got all twisted up before and I think I was trying to get the page pre-process variables from a region template override, but got things working now. thanks for the clear, concise guidance.

Comment: UPDATE: just wanted to note that this works if the page--landing template is in a sub-theme, but if the template is in a custom module, it does not execute the barrio theme page pre-process function and that was the root of my problem. Not sure why it works in a sub-theme and not a custom module, but I can make do putting it in a sub-theme.

Comment: UPDATE 2: I figured out that I can move my `page--landing` template, back from the sub-theme into in my custom module and still get the theme's (or sub-theme's) barrio bootstrap page pre-process function to run by adding a `'base hook' => 'page'` parameter to my template registration for `'page__landing'` inside `my_custom_module_theme` hook.