# Template override doesn't work

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to develop a Drupal 8 module in which I have to override the html.html.twig template. The idea is that I do not want any of the default html.html.twig template returned instead I only want the custom template returned. I have been spending hours Google hunting and trying to make sense of the many examples and I have gotten myself totally confused.

What is happening is the content of my custom template are being displayed in the default html template so I am seeing the custom content inside the default html template rather than overriding the default content.

For the sake of getting this template override working I have simplified the module as much as possible and simply want to return the contents of a variable into a placeholder in the twig template. Once this override is working I can go back and add the code that will create the correct content to be output into a number of variables in the template.

What I do not understand is exactly how to I override the html.html.twig template.

My module is called unsw_blocks and in the unsw_blocks.module I have the following

```
function unsw_blocks_theme() {

$theme = [
'unsw_blocks' => [
     'variables' => ['test_var' => NULL],
    ],
];

return $theme;
}
```

In the Unsw_blocksController.php have the following

```
class Unsw_blocksController extends ControllerBase {

  public function unsw_blocks($name) {
  return [
    '#theme' => 'unsw_blocks',
    '#test_var' => $this->t('The variable called test_var simply passes this text itself to the theme template'),
  ];
  }
}
```

In the custom modules templates directory I have unsw-blocks.html.twig which simply contains

```
<h1>Testing Template</h1>

<p>test_var: {{ test_var }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

HI please follow the below steps.

Step 1: create routing file
**docroot\modules\custom\product\product.routing.yml**

```
product.custom_form:
  path: '/product/details/{product}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\product\Controller\ProductDetailsController::details'
    _title: 'Product Details'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
  options:
    parameters:
      product:
        type: entity:node
```

Step 2: Create a controller: **modules\custom\product\src\Controller\ProductDetailsController.php**

```
   /**
   * Callback for route product.custom_form.
   */
  public function details($product) 
   
    return [
      '#theme' => 'product-details',
      '#content' => [
        '#contextual_links' => [
          'node' => [
            'route_parameters' => ['node' => $product->id()],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      '#product' => $product,
      
    ];
  }
```

Step 3: In your theme create a file following the directory **themes\custom\mytheme\templates\product-details.html.twig**

```
<div class="my-form-class">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>{{ product.title.value }}</h1>
        <h2>
            {% if product.field_title_description %}
                {{ product.field_title_description.value }}
            {% endif %}
        </h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't override html.twig in a module, but you can create module with a route and a controller that returns a Symfony response to bypass this limitation. There is background-information and a code example in this question:

[Override html.twig.html within custom module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184806/override-html-twig-html-within-custom-module)